# RFI response form asks for "Assumptions" as just a single money amount

Tags: estimation, cost-management, project-proposal

I am surprised by the last row in this [RFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_information) response form:

[image]

My project's initial fees are 1m$, recurring fees are 100k$/year, under the assumption that I provide only the software and they run it on their own hardware. If I had to provide the hardware too that would cost double. In my internal expense calculations, I calculated how much everything actually costs me and then I added +10% to account for risks.

- Should I write `Add 1m$ initial + 100k$/year for hardware` in the `Assumptions` field?
- Or should I fill the three fields with `900k$`, `90k$/year`, `100k$ initial + 10k$/year`?
- Or does it mean something entirely different?

The field is very small, preventing me from writing anything more than a number.

*I managed to [find](https://d2myx53yhj7u4b.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/IC-RFI-With-Cover-Letter-Template-WORD.dotx) the template for this RFI on the Internet, unfortunately it does not seem to provide much more information.*

Comment: I have never seen a request for a dollar amount against one's assumptions. Do you have a Q&A opportunity? If so, get clarification.

Comment: @DavidEspina: Yes, I have Q&A opportunity, but I would like to be sure before asking, as it might be obvious to very experienced project managers (after all, this template is used by many companies). Thanks for your insight, feel free to post an answer so that others can upvote it if they think the same :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you provided, the next field (after `ASSUMPTIONS`) is called `PRICING  METHODOLOGY.`

I think that's where they expect you to explain yourself. Pick one of your 3 answers and then explain yourself in the `PRICING  METHODOLOGY` field.

<sup>(That's assuming you don't get a clear answer when asking them in the Q&A session.)</sup>

Comment: Do you mean I can put `ASSUMPTIONS $0` and then just explain that all assumptions I made in the `PRICING  METHODOLOGY` field? That would be the easiest I guess. Thanks!